# Bootstrap 3 can't use dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 3 and i have menu. But I have problem with dropdown menu.

I can't use dropdown menu because it disappears so fast. Also it shows on hover very fast without animations

my html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="menu-item dropdown"><a title="Sample Page" href="#">Sample Page <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a title="Front Page" href="#">Front Page</a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a title="Front Page" href="#">Front Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.nav>li {
    float: left;
}

.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2000;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you make a working sample/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` to your Sample Page `<a>`

```css
.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  //display: none;
  z-index: 2000;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="menu-item dropdown ">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Sample Page" href="#">Sample Page <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a title="Front Page" href="#">Front Page</a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a title="Front Page" href="#">Front Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```